# How to automatically add (or let tfs2015 discover) build agent capabilities?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

How can I add a capability to a build agent in TFS 2015?

For example, I would like to install a build tool (on a TFS2015 build agent) and register this as a TFS Build agent capability.

I know that I can add this capability manually, through the web interface, but how to do it with a script?

I've read that TSF2015 discovers build agent capabilities alone, but.. how to instruct it about 'how to detect *my* build tool' ?

### References

I've read so far:

http://nakedalm.com/using-build-vnext-capabilities-demands-system/
http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext

Comment: It looks like there's no way to instruct it how to detect the capability automatically. You'll have to add it manually via the web UI. Although this sounds like a good idea and worth suggesting at visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: somebody else has asked the same question elsewhere:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/528

Comment: somebody says that environment variables affect capabilities list:
http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2015/07/25/how-to-register-capabilities-on-your-build-and-release-management-agents

Comment: Hmm, that sounds interesting. At least the idea with environment variables seems to cover most of the basic scenarios, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits go to Donovan Brown and [its blog post](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2015/07/25/how-to-register-capabilities-on-your-build-and-release-management-agents)

I have tried the solution it proposes, and it works in my scenario/environment:

1. set an environment variable during the software setup
2. this variable and its value will appear as agent capabilities in the TFS agent resume

According to a [GitHub issue](http://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/528), this functionality will eventually appear in npm scripts accompanying vso-build-tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Agent capabilities you can define custom "user capabilities" 
I added a custom user capability called

- "Tag" and set it to VS2015

In my build definition under General, under Demands, I added a demand that

- "Tag" equals VS2015

This will now force my build to that specific Pool (or agent)

For example I installed a 3rd Party utility to one of my build agents and added to the Agent user capabilities "AutoIt" = True. In my build, under General, Demands, I added one called "AutoIt" exists, this forces this build to the agent with the 3rd party utility that is installed.